# How to take String input from console in Java?

Tags: java

This is my code in Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class calc
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean go=true;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(go)
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int total;
        int choice;

        System.out.println("\nHi This is Console type Calculator");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Substraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply");
        System.out.println("4. Divisoin");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice : ");
        choice=input.nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter First Number");
                num1=input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
                num2=input.nextInt();
                total=num1+num2;
                System.out.println("Addition of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter First Number");
                num1=input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
                num2=input.nextInt();
                total=num1-num2;
                System.out.println("Substraction of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter First Number");
                num1=input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
                num2=input.nextInt();
                total=num1*num2;
                System.out.println("Multiplication of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Enter First Number");
                num1=input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
                num2=input.nextInt();
                total=num1/num2;
                System.out.println("Divistion of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please Choose right option...Try again");
                break;  
        }

        System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
        String str=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
        String str1=input.nextLine();

        if("no".equals(str1))
        {
            go=false;
            System.out.println("Thanks For using...Bye");
        }   
    }   
}
}
```

And I have problem in the following portion of code as taking input. This is not taking any input from user skip this part. Is there any problem in this code.

```
        System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
        String str1=input.nextLine();

        if("no".equals(str1))
        {
            go=false;
            System.out.println("Thanks For using...Bye");
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell what value do you get in str1?

Comment: Read about [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: @GurwinderSingh It doesn't take any input in str1.

Comment: You might want to try using `Scanner.next`, that will search for the next complete token.

Comment: use `if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){}` in place of `if("no".equals(str1))`

Comment: @Mathur it's not that much better. You should do `"no".equalsIgnoreCase(str1);`. Then it's better

Comment: because after `input.nextInt()` you have to do another `getLine()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is you were using `nextInt()` in your cases, so your string stored is the new line. All you have to do is replace:

```
    System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
    String str1=input.nextLine();

    if("no".equals(str1))
    {
        go=false;
        System.out.println("Thanks For using...Bye");
    }
```

by:

```
    System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
    input.nextLine(); // this is what I added
    String str1=input.nextLine();

    if("no".equals(str1))
    {
        go=false;
        System.out.println("Thanks For using...Bye");
    }
```

You can remove the following as those 2 lines serve no useful purpose:

```
    System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
    String str=input.nextLine();
```

Explanation: the `input.nextLine();` that I added basically captures the new line character when you hit enter or return. Next, you will have to call `input.nextLine()` again and assign it to `str1` to capture the string you intended to use.
Also, a small note on your program: if a user were to type in No, your program still considers the value as Yes, because it will change go to false only if no is lower case. A solution to that would be to convert the string you receive to lower case by calling `str1.toLowerCase()`. Also, you might want to check for an explicit yes answer, because a user might type dog and your program still considers it as a yes.

Comment: What about just `if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){}`?

Comment: @YoungMillie works equally well without any particular advantages though. Same computational cost. But +1 for more suggestions.

Comment: @YoungMillie Not really. toLowerCase will still convert every ASCII character to lowerCase while equalsIgnoreCase will exactly do the same number of comparisons even at the compiler level. --> Compiler Design course completed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because of the fact that you pick `nextInt` earlier. The user inputs a number and a new line character. You pick the number and the new line character is kept buffered. When you perform `nextLine()` it reads all characters between what is being pointed and the next `EOL`. It reads empty String as it's in the buffer before `\n` and then another `nextLine()` requires the program to wait for the input.

When you put a breakpoint after `String str = input.nextLine()` you'll see that it is actually empty `String`: `""`.

[image]

So instead of:

```
    System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
    String str=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
    String str1=input.nextLine();
```

You should write:

```
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation...Yes/No");
    String str1=input.nextLine();
```

Comment: That's a basic mistake with the scanner. Should be explain in every good tutorial...

Comment: Why wouldn't you use, `input.next()`? I think they are looking for the next complete token, not the next line.

Comment: @matt maybe... It's not the case